# Null value of DataReader in List(of string) vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, stored-procedures

I am writing a web service function in VB.net in a stored procedure in SQL server. I think the DataReader does not return any value.

Here is my stored procedure in Sql Server:

```
Create proc getVillageName
@village varchar(50)
as
Begin
    SELECT
    lookup_table.value FROM dbo.lookup_table INNER JOIN dbo.lookup_description ON 
    lookup_table.group_id = lookup_description.desc_id WHERE 
    lookup_description.description = 'Village' AND 
    lookup_table.value LIKE @village + '%'
End
```

Here is my code:

```
Public Function GetVillage(ByVal villageName As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim strsql As String
    Dim Villagevalue As List(Of String)
    Dim param As SqlParameter
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection With {.ConnectionString = "Server=MINTOY_DEV\MIGSSERVER;Database=SouthLinkDBO;User=sa;Pwd=123;"}
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader

    Using conn
        strsql = "getVillageName"
        cmd = New SqlCommand(strsql, conn)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        param = New SqlParameter("@village", villageName)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(param)

        conn.Open()
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While reader.Read
            Villagevalue.Add(reader.Item("value").ToString)
        End While

    End Using
End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing a line:

```
        While reader.Read
            Villagevalue.Add(reader.Item("value").ToString)
        End While

    End Using

    Return Villagevalue '<-----------------
End Function
```

Are you looking at compiler warnings? VB will tell you if you forget a `Return` statement.

Better yet, open the Project Properties, click on the Compiler tab, and set "Function returning a reference type without a return value" to "Error".

---

Also, how is this working at all?

```
Dim Villagevalue As List(Of String)
```

That should be

```
Dim Villagevalue As New List(Of String)
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of things we can improve here:

```
Public Iterator Function GetVillage(ByVal villageName As String) As IEnumerable(Of String)
    Using conn As New SqlConnection("Server=MINTOY_DEV\MIGSSERVER;Database=SouthLinkDBO;User=sa;Pwd=123;"), _
          cmd As New SqlCommand("getVillageName", conn)

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@village", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = villageName
        conn.Open()

        Using rdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            While reader.Read()
                Yield DirectCast(reader("value"), String)
            End While
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

The big thing is we **actually return a value** (`Yield` handles this for `Iterator` functions).

If you *really* need an actual `List(Of String)` (Hint: you usually don't; Your code will almost always perform a lot better if you arrange things to work with `IEnumerable(Of T)` for as long as possible) you can append a `.ToList()` when calling this method.